# What is the difference between virtual function and virtual destructor function?

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Base () { cout << "Base Dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void doSomething () { cout << "Base do something" << endl; }
};

class Derive : public Base {
    public:
    ~Derive () { cout << "Derive Dtor" << endl; }
    void doSomething () { cout << "Derive do something" << endl; }
};
```

when I try to write some code like:

```
Base* ptr = new Derive;
ptr->doSomething ();
delete ptr;
```

the function `doSomething()` is called correctly. Why the derived destructor is called and then base destructor is called? But `doSomething()` just only call the derived class's version. Destructor and `doSomething()` are also function but why do they behave differently?

Comment: Because that's what desturctors have to to: destroy the entire object, which is done by invoking the base class's destructor.

Comment: Calling a destructor via a *base* class pointer will call the base destructor *statically* if the base destructor is not `virtual`. But if the base destructor is `virtual`, then the *derived* destructor is called polymorphically, like any other virtual method. However, like constructors, destructors are special in that they always call the base automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object destructors are special. Yes, they are functions, but they actually represent something particular. Namely, destroying an object.

In your example `Derive` is an object. But through inheritance, `Derive` has a base class subobject called `Base`. That is, for every `Derive`, there is also a `Base` living *within* that `Derive` object.

When you invoke a constructor to create a `Derive`, the appropriate constructor will be invoked for the `Base` subobject as well (depending on how you defined your `Derive` constructor). As such, if you destroy a `Derive`, the `Base` living inside of it must *also* be destroyed.

The `virtual` call to the destructor doesn't actually change this. What it being `virtual` does is allow the system to start the chain of destructors *correctly*. If you had not declared the `Base` destructor to be `virtual`, then invoking `delete` on a base class pointer would only invoke `~Base`. It wouldn't be able to jump up the inheritance graph to call `~Derive`; the `delete` expression is given a `Base` pointer to delete, so that's what it does.

This is the same mechanism as any `virtual` call. If you didn't make a regular member function `virtual`, and you call it on a `Base` class pointer, then you get the `Base` version of it, even if there is a `Derive` version with the same name. You need `virtual` to make the compiler jump up the inheritance graph and find the right function to call.

But once the compiler knows the right object type to start the chain of destructors, that chain of object destruction will still happen. `Derive` contains a `Base`, so for a `Derive` to be destroyed, its `Base` must also be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the derived destructor is called and then base destructor is called?

Because a destructor always destroys all sub objects. This includes the bases.

Answer (score 0):

You overrided the `doSomething` function, that's why it executes only on `Derive` object you declared.

You can see destructors have different names. When you invoke some object's destructor, automatically father's destructor is invoked too.